# Is there any way to specify --endpoint-url in aws cli config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, amazon-iam

The aws command is

`aws s3 ls --endpoint-url http://s3.amazonaws.com`

can I load endpoint-url from any config file instead of passing it as a parameter?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is an [open bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1270) in the AWS CLI. There's a link there to [a cli plugin](https://github.com/wbingli/awscli-plugin-endpoint) which might do what you need.

It's worth pointing out that if you're just connecting to standard Amazon cloud services (like S3) you don't need to specify `--endpoint-url` at all.  But I assume you're trying to connect to some other private service and that url in your example was just, well, an example...

Comment: Yes I am trying to connect to a private service

Comment: Thanks for linking to that bug report. I was happy to find that after 8 years, they finally fixed it....yesterday! Use `export AWS_ENDPOINT_URL=http://localhost:5000` with aws-cli >=1.23.0:
* https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1270#issuecomment-1626070761
* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-ss-endpoints.html

Answer (score 39):

```
alias aws='aws --endpoint-url http://website'
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but seems like alias is hardcoding aws cli command instead I need a --endpoint-url option to be loaded from configuration file.

Comment: for some reason that didn't work for me, so I used a function: `function aws() { /usr/local/bin/aws --endpoint foo "${@}" }`  then later `unset -f aws`

Comment: This command must be written in `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc`

Comment: That is actually a smooth solution for test setups inside containers since the only actor using this alias, is the test runner itself.

Answer (score 4):

#### Updated Answer

Here is an alternative alias to address the OP's specific need and comments above

```
alias aws='aws $([ -r "$SOME_CONFIG_FILE" ] && sed "s,^,--endpoint-url ," $SOME_CONFIG_FILE) '
```

The `SOME_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable could point to a `aws-endpoint-override` file containing

```
http://localhost:4566
```

#### Original Answer

Thought I'd share an alternative version of the alias

```
alias aws='aws ${AWS_ENDPOINT_OVERRIDE:+--endpoint-url $AWS_ENDPOINT_OVERRIDE} '
```

This idea I replicated from another alias I use for Terraform

```
alias terraform='terraform ${TF_DIR:+-chdir=$TF_DIR} '
```

I happen to use [direnv](https://direnv.net/) with an `/Users/darren/Workspaces/current-client/.envrc` containing

```
source_up

PATH_add bin

export AWS_PROFILE=saml
export AWS_REGION=eu-west-1

export TF_DIR=/Users/darren/Workspaces/current-client/infrastructure-project

...
```

A possible workflow for AWS-endpoint overriding could entail `cd`'ing into a `docker-env` directory, where `/Users/darren/Workspaces/current-client/app-project/docker-env/.envrc` contains

```
source_up

...

export AWS_ENDPOINT_OVERRIDE=http://localhost:4566
```

where LocalStack is running in Docker, exposed on port `4566`.

You may not be using Docker or LocalStack, etc, so ultimately you will have to provide the `AWS_ENDPOINT_OVERRIDE` environment variable via a mechanism and with an appropriate value to suit your use-case.

Comment: Note that, within `.envrc`, you can define the value for `AWS_ENDPOINT_OVERRIDE` using other environment variables or any means supported by Bash; the benefit here is that the updates to the value are triggered by `cd`'ing between directories and can take values derived (or not) from the directory `cd`'ed to

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into this issue, here are my findings.

**Context**

The team is writing Python code that will run in AWS Lambda.

**Situation**

The team wants to run the solution locally as deploying code changes in AWS means long feedback loops.

We decided to use LocalStack and Serverless to shorten the feedback loops.

But! Some automation is required to have a local development environment with all dependencies, including the ones above.

**Problem**

[The LocalStack documentation](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/serverless-framework/#adjust-aws-endpoints-in-lambda-functions) suggests the Lambda code to contain the following:

```
...
if 'LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME' in os.environ:
  dynamodb_endpoint = 'http://%s:4566' % os.environ['LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME']
  dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url=dynamodb_endpoint)
else:
  dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
...
```

There's a better way. Think about it, Lambda code should contain "business logic" only, it should be environment-agnostic, and also tooling-agnostic.

**Solution**

As `boto3` is smart enough to load the `awscli` config and credentials files, AWS released a change that allows developers define an `endpoint_url` in the `~/.aws/config` file. [As documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-ss-endpoints.html)

In our case, the automation code will make sure the local environment has a config file with the following contents

```
[profile localstack]                                                                                                      
output = json
region = eu-west-2
endpoint_url = http://localhost:4566
```

This `endpoint_url` value is the first bit of the output from the command:

```
awslocal sqs create-queue --queue-name local-in-queue
```

So this is how my code using `sqs` looks like:

```
sqs_client = boto3.resource("sqs")
```

No need to define the `endpoint_url` argument. No need to define the `AWS_PROFILE` or the `AWS_REGION` OS environment variables. When `boto3` loads within my local environment the "fake" Lambda has everything it needs to run fine.

Answer (score 2):

The latest AWS CLI does provide this functionality as mentioned in their [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-endpoints.html).

The simplest way is to add the following in your config file, generally `~/.aws/config`, which will apply it globally for the default profile.

```
[default]
endpoint_url = http://localhost:9001
...
```

For more granular control refer to the docs linked above.

Answer (score -1):

```
If you are accessing aws S3 bucket hosted in eu-central-1 region using *environment variable* then add *AWS_ENDPOINT_URL=https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com*
after export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="abevdhdjdkdo", export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="abevdhdjdkdoabevdhdjdkdo", export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="abevdhdjdkdo12334" use this  export AWS_ENDPOINT_URL="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"

In using aws configure, then add another line "endpoint_url = https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" vim ~/.aws/config after region/output.
Example:
[default]
region = eu-central-1
output = text
endpoint_url = https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Note: Change the region name where your buckets are located.
```

Comment: It seems that this answer is not formatted correctly. It appears that there are text sections and 2 separate code sections? It's not entirely clear how it should be formatted (hence why I just edited out the fluff and left the rest as is)